# Infrastructure Automation with GitLab

Tags: automation, infrastructure-as-code, workflow

I am looking to validate the use of devops for a team of seven people, each having a specific function.

1 Java Developer
1 System Administrator
1 Team Lead/Project Manager
1 Identity Management Admin
2 Access Management Admin
1 PKI Registration Agent

We have different workflows for each function. However, from my perspective, it's all the same. New ideas or requirements bring about new or changes to code, which initiates the workflow.  To me, application updates, OS patching, and innovation are all the same. Could CI/CD pipelines be created to standardize infrastructure security and configuration as well as enable a faster and more feature tuned application release cycle?  Any input would be most appreciated.

-Darryl

Comment: Hi and welcome to DevOps.SE. DevOps is merely a flowery (but to-the-point) term for automating infrastructure tasks surrounding development and operation of (software) services. I think you're right to see those commonalities, but I'd argue that doesn't equate to a "one size fits all" model but rather that the same or similar tools can be used to facilitate the workflows you identified. I for one would not automate all aspects of application updates the same as OS patches (think human approval in the process). But a question: are those roles or 1:1 matches of roles:people?

Comment: Thanks for the engagement. Yes the number next to the role of the number of individuals in that role. I appreciate your comment concerning approvals. That is an important thing to remember.

Answer (score 2):

here are my 2 cents,

1. You can use GITLAB to have merge requests for all your security requests like adding users to the groups for every new user or existing users. the Mr can be approved by only your IAM admin. You can use GITLAB CI pipelines to go and perform the operation once the MR is approved. From the users side, the user has to  provide their keys and submit as an MR so that the IAM team can validate and approve it.
2. You can deploy your applications easily using Ansible and Gitlab CI. All you need is just source code of your application and some knowledge of YAML. I am sure, your folks already are equipped with that. Ansible can be used for infra provisioning as well so you can just run the show with them. With regards to os updates, I would say ansible can easily do it. Have the SDLC workflow in place for developing playbooks and once the playbook is modularized, it can used in production.

Let me know if I answered your query and if you have any other questions.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Sreekar.  I appreciate the detail.  Based on you comments, I'd like to ask you what is your team doing in this regard?

Comment: Well, I have illustrated what we are doing here only :) However we don't have any separate roles like IAM admin, etc. Also, we have used terraform for infra provisioning as we felt its win over ansible with regards to the TF state file. It was concluded to use terraform after many calculations. I haven't suggested you because you specifically asked for ansible. If you have a choice, I suggest to go with terraform for infra provisioning.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of ways to automatize you infrastructure. For your pipelines you can use a tool for this like Jenkins, Travis CI, GitLab, Concourse CI, Drone IO and through turn better CI/CD for your developer.

From the perspective of automating the infra, you can use Terraform to raise it, manage to maintain the default using Ansible and to handle jobs you can use Rundeck.

But the more important it's you plan how to you link these tools.

Comment: Thank you for your input. The desire is to utilize GitLab and Ansible as much as possible. It's nice to know that there are real options for told as well.

Comment: @ddarling GitLab have a tools for CI/CD, sincerely I never used, but see a lot of professionals talking good about them.